# Using @WebFluxTest to test RouterFunction

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, spock, spring-webflux

I've got a router function that I want to test using `spock`. It looks like this

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

    /**
     * Router function.
     * @return string
     */
    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<?> helloRoute() {
        return route(GET("/judge/router/hello"),
                request -> ServerResponse.ok().body(fromPublisher(Mono.just("Hello Router WebFlux"), String.class)));
    }

}
```

The test for it looks like this

```
@WebFluxTest
class JudgeRuleEngineMvcTestSpec extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    WebTestClient webClient;

    def "router function returns hello"() {
        expect:
            webClient.get().uri("/judge/router/hello")
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .expectBody(String.class)
                .isEqualTo("Hello WebFlux") // should fail
    }
}
```

But it fails because instead of `200` status it returns `404`. It seems it cannot find the `REST` itself.

I also has a test for basic `RestController` with `GetMapping` and it works fine.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/judge/rest")
public class BasicController {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BasicController.class);

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public Mono<String> handle() {
        LOGGER.debug("Invoking hello controller");
        return Mono.just("Hello WebFlux");
    }

}

def "mvc mono returns hello"() {
    expect:
        webClient.get().uri("/judge/rest/hello")
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isOk()
            .expectBody(String.class)
                .isEqualTo("Hello WebFlux")
}
```

Why it fails with router function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a known limitation of `@WebFluxTest` - there is currently no consistent way to detect `RouterFunction` beans, just like we do for `@Controller` classes.

See [this Spring Boot issue for future reference](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10683).

Comment: So there is no way to test them? Without direct method invocation or some embedded server?

Comment: there's no `@WebFluxTest` equivalent for now - so yes, embedded server or testing them directly is the way to go.

Comment: with the rise of embedded databases it is time for embedded server testing lol

Answer (score 3):

To add to [Brian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48843944/724485) there seems to be a workaround mentioned by kizux in that Github issue link he posted

You can use `bindToApplicationContext` to test the router function using WebTestClient

Quoting

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {RouteConfiguration.class, UserHandler.class})
@WebFluxTest
public class UserHandlerTest
{
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;
    @MockBean(name="userService")
    private UserService userService;
    private WebTestClient testClient;

    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        testClient = WebTestClient.bindToApplicationContext(context).build();
    }

    ...
```